# UILocal Notifications

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

In my app I am scheduling a notification and repetition for every 10 sec, and in the notification did receive method I am printing the total number of notifications with this code:

```
NSArray *scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
NSLog(@"%d",scheduledNotifications.count);
```

After printing I am removing that notification. When the app is in active state I am getting proper count, but after entering to background for 30 sec I am getting 3 notifications, after clicking on any notification, in the notification did receive method count is printing as "one" only, instead of three...?

Any Solution please...

Answer (score 0):

You will not receive all notification in the app when you app is started when the user click/swipes on a notification. iOS will only tell your app which notification was used to open your app. The other local notification will not be presented to the app.

What you could do is look thru all the local notifications and check wether the fire date is passed. Meaning that the notification has probably been presented to the user. Then remove that notification.

Comment: All the notifications are presenting properly,User can perform the  same action(did receive notification) directly by entering in to app with out clicking on notification,at that time i want do remove that notification

Comment: When I say presented to the app I mean that you app will only receive the notification the user used to open you app. All other notification in the notification center will not be passed to your app, thus you can't find out which notification are still in the notification center. Your only option is to loop thru the local notification and remove those who's firedate is in the past.